# cxfreeze produces SyntaxError exception in oauthlib when attempting to convert Python script to Windows executable

Tags: python, exception, oauth, syntax-error, cx-freeze

I'm attempting to convert a Python 3.2.2 program to a Windows executable using `cxfreeze`. The "`getstats.py`" program I've written runs just fine from the compiler and from the command line. When I run `cxfreeze src\getstats.py` on my Windows command line to compile it, I get a lengthy chain of exceptions, culminating in a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\Scripts\cxfreeze", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\main.py", line 188, in main
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 470, in Freeze
    self._FreezeExecutable(executable)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 144, in _FreezeExecutable
    scriptModule = finder.IncludeFile(exe.script, exe.moduleName)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 492, in IncludeFile
    deferredImports)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 352, in _LoadModule
    self._ScanCode(module.code, module, deferredImports)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 440, in _ScanCode
    module, relativeImportIndex)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 218, in _ImportModule
    deferredImports, namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 305, in _InternalImportModule
    parentModule, namespace)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 317, in _LoadModule
    namespace)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 362, in _LoadPackage
    self._LoadModule(name, fp, path, info, deferredImports, parent)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 352, in _LoadModule
    self._ScanCode(module.code, module, deferredImports)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 440, in _ScanCode
    module, relativeImportIndex)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 254, in _ImportModule
    deferredImports, namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 305, in _InternalImportModule
    parentModule, namespace)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 352, in _LoadModule
    self._ScanCode(module.code, module, deferredImports)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 440, in _ScanCode
    module, relativeImportIndex)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 254, in _ImportModule
    deferredImports, namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 305, in _InternalImportModule
    parentModule, namespace)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 352, in _LoadModule
    self._ScanCode(module.code, module, deferredImports)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 440, in _ScanCode
    module, relativeImportIndex)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 218, in _ImportModule
    deferredImports, namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 289, in _InternalImportModule
    namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 305, in _InternalImportModule
    parentModule, namespace)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 317, in _LoadModule
    namespace)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 362, in _LoadPackage
    self._LoadModule(name, fp, path, info, deferredImports, parent)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 352, in _LoadModule
    self._ScanCode(module.code, module, deferredImports)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 440, in _ScanCode
    module, relativeImportIndex)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 254, in _ImportModule
    deferredImports, namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 305, in _InternalImportModule
    parentModule, namespace)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 317, in _LoadModule
    namespace)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 362, in _LoadPackage
    self._LoadModule(name, fp, path, info, deferredImports, parent)
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 330, in _LoadModule
    module.code = compile(codeString, path, "exec")
  File "C:\MyPython\Python\Python32\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\__init__.py", line 18
    SIGNATURE_HMAC = u"HMAC-SHA1"

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is my first time attempting to use `cxfreeze` so I'm not really sure what might be broken here. The only "non-standard" module in use in this program is `requests`. Ideas?

Comment: Not sure if this is something which might be fixed by using a `setup.py` script for `cx_freeze` or not?

Comment: Nope. Same error when using a simple distutils script. Figured it would be, but I had to be sure.

Comment: Does it need oauthlib? Can you just remove it? Because that line *isn't* valid in Python 3.2.